# Doxygen LaTeX syntax

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-tex, filetype-markdown

I am using [doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/) to document my code and I like to have additional markdown files which [include formulas](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/formulas.html) by using `\f$ Formula \f$`.

I know markdown syntax provided by the [vim-markdown](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown) plugin supports LaTeX formulas highlighting when using `$ Formula $`. So far, I haven't found any plugin supporting the doxygen formulas format.

What can I do to get LaTeX syntax highlighting in the doxygen format?